# Kendo treeview HierarchicalDataSource not showing child nodes

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview

I have a kendo Treeview which is showing the parent nodes but the child nodes are not seen. Can anyone tell me where am i going wrong. I am new to this concept. I followed the below link but its not working.
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/remote-data-binding

```
 function treeView() {
        var treeM = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    console.log("response" + JSON.stringify(response));
                    var rdata = {};
                    if (response.d) {
                        rdata = JSON.parse(response.d);
                    }
                    else {
                        rdata = response;
                    }
                    return rdata; // ASMX services return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }.
                },
                model: {
                    hasChildren: true,
                    id: "ID",
                    expanded: true,
                    fields: {
                        ID: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                        LINK: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                                          },
                },
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/getParent",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if ((type == "update") || (type == "create") || (type == "destroy")) {
                        console.log('parameterMap:');
                        return JSON.stringify({ "LinksJson": data });
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    } else {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

                 $("#treeview1").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: treeM,
            dataValueField: "ID",
            dataTextField: ["LINK","Name"]
        });

    }

    $("#treeview").on("click", ".k-in", function (e) {
        var tree = $("#treeview").data('kendoTreeView');
        tree.toggle($(e.target).closest(".k-item"));
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        treeView();
    });
```

Service:

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string getParent()
    {
        using (var context = new Data.Entities())
        {
            IQueryable<ERPv2.Data.Links> dataQuery = from x in context.Links
                                                          where x.ParentID == 68
                                                         select x;
            var newQry = dataQuery.AsEnumerable().Select(c => new
                         {
                             ID = c.ID,
                              Name = c.Name,
                             Children = HasChildren(231)
                         });
            JavaScriptSerializer JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return JSON.Serialize(newQry);

        }
    }




      [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public bool HasChildren(int ID)
        {
            using (var context = new Data.Entities())
            {
                IQueryable<ERPv2.Data.Links> dataQuery = from x in contextLinks
                                                             where x.ParentID == ID
                                                             select x;

                return dataQuery.AsEnumerable().Any();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when you try to view the child nodes, it will try to call getLinks and not the getreports. 
From what i have seen , you should have only one method for getting parent and children. Can be an array inside each parent node. 
Can you combine the data from GetReports method inside getlinks itsself and give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your advice i have been trying what you said from 1 day but somehow i am unable to write the query. I have added the LINQ query can please check it and suggest me and updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You should try and get this working here with hardcoded values and then do configure with services.
 http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#configuration-dataSource